# How to Convert an Inline annotation file into a GATE annotation file?

Tags: annotations, nlp, inline, gate

Gate Developer can save both it's annotation files in two formats, GATE XML or Inline XML. If I saved one file as Inline XML, can I convert it to a GATE XML using  Gate Embedded?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just load a GATE document from the Inline XML file and save it as GATE XML (see the `gate.Document.toXml()` method). But be aware that Inline XML is potentially a lossy format...

Comment: Got it! Thank you.